# Strange output combining Tee-object and $(Get-Date)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to append output to a .txt file. My command is as follows:

```
ni C:\example\example.txt -type file -value "`n$(Get-Date)"|out-null
$CSVvariable | sort Property | Format-Table | Tee-Object -Append -FilePath C:\example\example.txt
```

When I run the command I get the following output in the .txt file:

《⼹㔰㈯㄰″㤱㐺㨹
(The table is being presented correctly.)

$(Get-Date) seems to become the above symbols. Anyone have an idea why ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to use `format-table` inside a pipeline like this.  The output of `format-table` is a collection of "formatting objects" that the host interprets and are pretty much incomprehensible.  The last time I checked, they weren't even documented well.

If you really want the table formatting, you can try adding `out-string` to the pipeline before the `tee-object`, but at that point you'll have a collection of strings, not "objects".

That's a separate issue from why you got strange characters, but I'd try removing the format-table and see how the file looks.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about the Format-Table formatting. Will try your suggestion first thing in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

What is your CultuerInfo?

```
([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture).DateTimeFormat
```

It seems like it might be set to something other than en-US.

Comment: I did find out that when I use the $(Get-Date) variable with the Add-Content Cmdlet I get a different outcome as when I use the Tee-Object Cmdlet. I can't for the life of me figure out why tho.